# Upload multiple files using Symfony form

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

**UPDATED**
In my Symfony project,I am able to upload single image.Now I am trying to upload multiple images.

```
class ImageFile extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('images', FileType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Insert Image','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','style'=>'margin-bottom:15px')))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => images::class
        ));
    }
}
```

In my **Images** entity, I keep an array of **SatellieImage** objects like this.

```
class images
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var satelliteImage[]
     * @ORM\Column(name="images", type="string")
     *
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * Set images
     *
     * @param string $images
     *
     * @return satelliteImage[]
     */
    public function setImages($images)
    {
        $this->images = $images;

        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Get images
     *
     * @return satelliteImage[]
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage($image)
    {
        $this->images[] = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I store the satelliteImage[] as $files and run a foreach loop to upload() each file (upload() function worked perfectly for single file)

```
public function uploadImages(Request $request)
    {
        $satelliteImage=new satelliteImage;
        $images=new images();

        $form = $this->createForm(ImageFile::class, $images);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $files=$images->getImages();

        foreach ($files as $file){
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $file->upload();

            $em->persist($satelliteImage);
            $em->flush();
        }
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Images inserted successfully'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('satellite_images');
    }
```

**Problem** : I get an error saying "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" How do I fix this?

Comment: So you haven't really read the answer posted below?

Comment: @Fyntasia, I did read that, but the problem is I have a different issue now. The 'Browse images' button does not appear....It probably might work if this issue is solved.

Comment: @MadhukaHarith Did you figure it out? Because I have the same problem, I can upload single image, but not multiple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think all you have to do here is add the 'multiple' attribute to your `ImageFile` class;

See [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/file.html#multiple).

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class ImageFile extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('images', FileType::class, [
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr'     => [
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Also, change your 'image' property, to 'images' property:

```
/**
 * Set images
 *
 * @param string $images
 *
 * @return satelliteImage[]
 */
public function setImages($images)
{
    $this->images = $images;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get images
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getImages()
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function addImage($image)
{
    $this->images[] = $image;

    return $this;
}
```

Once you have this sorted, you can modify your `upload` method to handle multiple files from the FormType.

Comment: I did that but still I get an error saying Could not load type "file"

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I've edited my post. Try passing the FileType this way.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, but after making that change I get an error saying Expected argument of type "string", "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType" given

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using? When looking at the symfony documentation, the 'file' string declaration should work. The problem you're having could be unrelated to the formtype.

Comment: I am using Symfony 3.2.1

Comment: Ah, great. Your tag said Symfony2. Try it with this modification please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132710/discussion-between-madhuka-harith-and-fyntasia).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe working example help you?
I make simple app with multipe file upload for symfony 3.*.
Here is link: https://github.com/marekz/example_symfony_multiply_files_example

First: Both form declatartion:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Form\FilesType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('name')
                ->add('lastName')
                ->add('files', CollectionType::class,array(
                    'entry_type' => FilesType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ))
                ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_user';
    }


}


    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FilesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Files'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_files';
    }


}
```

Now, my entities:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Files", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $files;

    function __construct() {
        $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName) {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Get files
     * 
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    function getFiles() {
        return $this->files;
    }

    /**
     * Set files
     * @param type $files
     */
    function setFiles($files) {
        $this->files = $files;
    }
}

    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Files
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return Files
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
    }
```

Finaly, Symfony Controller:

```
/**
 * Creates a new user entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $attachments = $user->getFiles();

        if ($attachments) {
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)
            {
                $file = $attachment->getFile();

                var_dump($attachment);
                $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' .$file->guessExtension();

                $file->move(
                        $this->getParameter('upload_path'), $filename
                );
                var_dump($filename);
                $attachment->setFile($filename);
            }
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
                'user' => $user,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course, you have right. I correct my message in this moment.

Answer (score 3):

I found this article that explain every detail in this question in symfony 5. I was very helpful to understand what is going on. If you are new, you can start here, then read question and you will sync.

The article: https://nouvelle-techno.fr/actualites/live-coding-upload-dimages-multiples-avec-symfony-4-et-5

Credit goes to Nouvelle-Techno.fr

The article is in french, please click on `translate this page` on your url bar if you are using chrome to translate to English.